# Correcting problems with Media Manager

Tags: migration, joomla-3.3.x

I recently moved a website to a different host and encountered problems with the Media Manager.  I'm running Joomla 3.3 and when I click on the Media Manager icon in the control panel I get the following 500 error

> View not found [name, type, prefix]: media, html, mediaView

Is this something I can debug myself or am I destined for a long wait with my host's customer service department?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few troubleshooting questions to think:

- Does your new hosting meet the system requirements for Joomla 3.3 ?
- Are you sure this was not a problem before you move ?
- Did you do the move at your own ?
- Try to restore again the website on another directory - or on your computer and see if the issue persists.
- Is it possible that you had file overrides or core files patched by a programmer, and then some of these get lost or doesn't work bacause of a Joomla update ?
- Or did you recently updated your website and have any outdated extensions ?
- Have you installed any new non-compatible extensions ?
- Check for any possible file permission issues.
- Try to replace the Joomla core files from a clean 3.3 installation...